# Is the field of formal Laurent series flat over the ground ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, laurent-series, localization

Let $\mathbb C[[x]]$ be the ring of formal power series in a single indeterminate $x$. Let $\mathbb C((x))$ be the field of formal Laurent series which can be seen as the fraction field of $\mathbb C[[x]]$. It is well known that $\mathbb C((x))$ is a flat $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module. Is $\mathbb C((x))$ flat over $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 3):

The complex numbers are a field and all modules over fields are free, therefore flat.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Thanks. Can you factor $\mathbb C((x))$ by the maximal ideal $(x)$ in $\mathbb C[[x]]$? $\mathbb C((x))$is a flat $C[[x]]$-module, so the result should be $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. What are you claiming that the final tensor product should be?

Comment: The field $\mathbb C((x))$ has (at least) two non-isomorphic $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module structures: One where $x$ acts by multiplication by $x$ and one where it acts as $0$. In the latter case, yes, we may essentially treat it as a $\mathbb C$-module since the action factors through the maximal ideal $(x)$.

Comment: Wait. $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$ is always a $\mathbb C$-module regardless of the $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module structure of $\mathbb C((x))$, right?

Comment: Also, $\mathbb C((x))$ has a $\mathbb C$-module structure by multiplication regardless of the $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module structure of $\mathbb C((x))$?

Comment: Both these assertions are correct.

Comment: If we have a $\mathbb C[[x]]$-algebra $B$ whose scalar field we extend to $\mathbb C((x))$ by setting $C:=B\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$, how do we compute the quotient $C/(x)$? Meaning do we get $C/(x)\cong  
 B\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}(\mathbb C((x))/(x))\cong B\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))\cong B/(x)\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$?

Comment: You say that both assertions are correct. Why did you then specify that when $x$ acts by multiplication by $0$, we can then view $\mathbb C((x))$ as a $\mathbb C$-module? Implying that in the case when $x$ acts by multiplication by $x$, we can't?

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. Your question in the comment was unclear to me so I was simply pointing out the two different module structures you have. Yes, if $x$ acts as zero, you can simply quotient out by the ideal it generates and get a $\mathbb C$ module structure without forgetting any information. Nowhere did I say that there isn’t such a module structure if $x$ does not act as 0. To spell everything out explicitly, If it doesn’t, you can just restrict the scalars to $\mathbb C$ to get a $\mathbb C$ module structure.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you for this clarification! I simply wanted to be certain that we are on the same page here. When we quotient $\mathbb C((x))$ by the ideal $(x)$, we mean that we quotient the $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module $\mathbb C((x))$ by the maximal ideal $(x)$ of the ring $\mathbb C[[x]]$, right? That is what one means. Because as a field, $\mathbb C((x))$ does not have any nontrivial proper ideals and $\mathbb C((x))/(x)$ would give $0$.

Comment: Correct, all quotienting action is on the ring $\mathbb C[[x]]$.

Comment: I was thinking about the module structures of $\mathbb C((x))$. Let $B$ be a $\mathbb C[[x]]$-algebra. Let $\mathbb C((x))$ be the $\mathbb C[[x]]$-module in which $x$ acts by multiplication by $x$. How is the tensor product $B/(x)\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$ defined for this module structure of $\mathbb C((x))$? See: if you move a formal power series from $\mathbb C((x))$ to $B/(x)$, it is truncated by the quotient $(x)$, then when you move it back to $\mathbb C((x))$, you are left with a complex number. So the initial and final elements are different which is not well-defined.

Comment: Please ask these as a separate question. As the site reminds us, the comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Thanks. Here is a link to one of these questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499816/tensor-product-of-localized-modules-over-quotient-rings-of-annihilators

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb C[[x]]/(x)\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$ actually equal to zero? For every $[z]\otimes k\in\mathbb C[[x]]/(x)\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$, we have $[z]\otimes k=[z]\otimes xx^{-1}k=[xz]\otimes x^{-1}k=0$.

Comment: Yes, therefore..?

Comment: Therefore, it is just the trivial $\mathbb C$-module. The trivial abelian group is a module over every ring. I originally thought that $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb C[[x]]}\mathbb C((x))$ was a nontrivial $\mathbb C$-module.